# jQuery dialog bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI dialog inside a function that is called by onClick event:

```
function showInCampaignOverlayBox(content_url) {
    $("#cpd-overlaybox-content").html('<img src="../daten/imgs/loading_bar_5.gif" class="cpd-overlaybox-centered-loader">');
    $("#cpd-overlaybox-content").attr('src', content_url);
    $("#cpd-overlaybox-dlg-header-label").html("Contenunit bulk edit ");

    $("#cpd-overlaybox-dialog").dialog({
        confirmationType: null,
        width:'90%',
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        dialogClass: 'view-cpd-overlaybox-dialog',
        close: function() {
            $("#cpd-overlaybox-content").attr('src', '');
            $(this).dialog("destroy");
        }
    });

    $('.cpd-overlaybox-element-exit_js').live('click', function(){
        $('span.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick').click();
    });
}
```

For some reason sometimes appears that error:

> Cannot read property 'appendTo' of undefined

and it refers to this line code inside JQuery UI widget library:

```
var c = (this.oldInstances.length ? this.oldInstances.splice(0, 1)[0] : b("<div></div>").appendTo ...
```

I figured out that this.oldInstances is not defined, how is possible?

Comment: Just as an aside, `live()` was deprecated and removed from jQuery a *long* time ago. You should really update the version of the library you're using. It may also be related to your issue in fact, if the version of jQueryUI you have is newer than the version of jQuery itself.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the jQuery version you are using?

Anyway you should replace `live()` with `on()` like this:

```
$('.cpd-overlaybox-element-exit_js').on('click', function(){
   $('span.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick').click();
)};
```

live() has been deprecated long time ago. [1](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: The version is jQuery UI Dialog 1.8rc3

Comment: And what about the JQuery?

Comment: could you provide a working plunkr? is not easy to reproduce in this way

Comment: i tried to reproduce your problem into a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ked7qqu1/

I wasn't able to get your error, check the versions on it

Comment: Why destroy the dialog?